# Splitting files evenly dividing based on number of rows in Windows

Tags: batch-file

Here is the problem I'm trying to solve:  Once a week 6 text files are placed in a directory, each with a variable number of records.  I need to divide each of these files into 5 other files (one for each weekday).  So after this process runs I will have 30 files.  I want this to be something I can run as a scheduled task so that I don't have to manually split these files out each week.

Example:
File One.txt has 1000 records, so it will be split into File One A.txt (200 records), File One B.txt (200 records), File One C.txt (200 records), File One C.txt (200 records), and File One D.txt (200 records)
File Two.txt may have 500 records, so it will be split into 5 files of 100 records.  (File Two A.txt, File Two B.txt, Etc.)

Constraints: I am running Windows Server 2008.  I cannot install any additional third party utilities and I don't want to have to compile the solution or install anything.  I'd prefer it to be a batch file if possible.

I've seen other examples here that look at strings within the files, but this has nothing do do with the content.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: What if your file has 1001 lines?  How will you divide it?

Comment: How do you want to split the files? First 200 records go in first file, second 200 the next, etc? Or do you want to alternate assignment of lines such that file 1 has lines 1,6,11,etc.? or...? And what does this have to do with days of the week?

Comment: It does not matter how the files are split. Whatever works easiest is fine.  The number of rows in each output file does not have to be exactly the same, so it is fine if the files are 201,200,200,200,200.  It doesn't matter if you put the first 200 in file one or if you divide them out like cards.

Comment: The days of the week is because I can only process so many records per weekday.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is untested:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem Create destination folder
md SplittedFiles 2>NUL
rem Process the 6 files
for %%a in (*.txt) do (
   rem Count number of records in this file
   for /F %%b in ('find /C /V "" ^< "%%a"') do set records=%%b
   rem Get Records per file and remaining records
   set /A recsPerFile=records/5, remaining=recsPerFile*5+1
   rem Split this file in 5 parts
   < "%%a" (
      for %%b in (A B C D E) do (
         (for /L %%c in (1,1,!recsPerFile!) do (
            set "record="
            set /P record=
            echo(!record!
         )) > "SplittedFiles\%%~Na %%b.txt"
      )
      rem Add remaining records to last part, if any
      (for /L %%c in (!remaining!,1,!records!) do (
         set "record="
         set /P record=
         echo(!record!
      )) >> "SplittedFiles\%%~Na E.txt"
   )
)
```

Previous program will modify records that may have exclamation marks; this point may be fixed, if required.

Comment: Initial testing is this works perfectly!  I will continue to test.  Thank you so much Aacini!

Comment: You may mark this answer as "Best Answer", this indicate that this question was answered and give me some rep points; you may also upvote this answer later, when you have enough rep points to do so...